# Spring Webflux(Mono/Flux) with AOP triggering REST call at interception and working with Mono/Flux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-webflux

I have written an @Aspect to intercept Reactive Methods that return values in Mono/Flux. Using @AfterReturning advice, i'm trying to fire an APNS notification by calling a webservice.

unfortunately the processNotification Mono services is immediately returning onComplete signal without executing the chain of calls. Below is my sample program.

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class NotifyAspect{
    private final NotificationServiceHelper notificationServiceHelper;

    @Autowired
    public NotifyAspect(NotificationServiceHelper notificationServiceHelper) {
        this.notificationServiceHelper = notificationServiceHelper;
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "@annotation(com.cupid9.api.common.annotations.Notify)", returning = "returnValue")
    public void generateNotification(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object returnValue) throws Throwable {
        log.info("AfterReturning Advice - Intercepting Method : {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getName());

        //Get Intercepted method details.
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();

        //Get the Notification Details.
        Notify myNotify = method.getAnnotation(Notify.class);
        if (Mono.class.isAssignableFrom(returnValue.getClass())) {
            Mono<Object> result = (Mono<Object>) returnValue;
            result.doOnSubscribe(o -> {
                log.debug("On Subscription...");
                notificationServiceHelper.processNotification(myNotify.notificationType())
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    log.error("Exception in notification processor",throwable);
                });
            });
        }
    }

}
```

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class NotificationServiceHelper {
    private ReactiveUserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

    @Value("${services.notification.url}")
    private String notificationServiceUrl;

    private RestWebClient restWebClient;

    @Autowired
    public NotificationServiceHelper(RestWebClient restWebClient,
                                     ReactiveUserProfileRepository reactiveUserProfileRepository) {
        this.restWebClient = restWebClient;
        this.userProfileRepository = reactiveUserProfileRepository;
    }

    public Flux<Notification> processNotification(NotificationSchema.NotificationType notificationType) {
        /*Get user profile details*/
        return SessionHelper.getProfileId()
                .switchIfEmpty( Mono.error(new BadRequest("Invalid Account 1!")))
                .flatMap(profileId ->
                        Mono.zip(userProfileRepository.findByIdAndStatus(profileId, Status.Active), SessionHelper.getJwtToken()))
                .switchIfEmpty( Mono.error(new BadRequest("Invalid Account 2!")))
                .flatMapMany(tuple2 ->{
                    //Get user details and make sure there are some valid devices associated.
                    var userProfileSchema = tuple2.getT1();
                    log.info("Processing Notifications for User Profile : {}", userProfileSchema.getId());
                    if (Objects.isNull(userProfileSchema.getDevices()) || (userProfileSchema.getDevices().size() < 1)) {
                        return Flux.error(new InternalServerError("No Devices associate with this user. Can not send notifications."));
                    }

                    //Build Notification message from the Notification Type
                    var notificationsMap = new LinkedHashSet<Notification>();
                    userProfileSchema.getDevices().forEach(device -> {
                        var notificationPayload = Notification.builder()
                                .notificationType(notificationType)
                                .receiverDevice(device)
                                .receiverProfileRef(userProfileSchema.getId())
                                .build();
                        notificationsMap.add(notificationPayload);
                    });

                    //Get session token for authorization
                    var jwtToken = tuple2.getT2();

                    //Build the URI needed to make the rest call.
                    var uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(notificationServiceUrl).build().toUri();
                    log.info("URI built String : {}", uri.toString());

                    //Build the Headers needed to make the rest call.
                    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                    headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, jwtToken);

                    var publishers = new ArrayList<Mono<ClientResponse>>();
                    notificationsMap.forEach(notification -> {
                        publishers.add(restWebClient.post(uri, headers, notification));
                    });
                    return Flux.merge(publishers).flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                        var httpStatus = clientResponse.statusCode();
                        log.info("NotificationService HTTP status code : {}", httpStatus.value());
                        if (httpStatus.is2xxSuccessful()) {
                            log.info("Successfully received response from Notification Service...");
                            return clientResponse.bodyToMono(Notification.class);
                        } else {
                            // return Flux.empty();
                            return clientResponse.bodyToMono(Error.class)
                                    .flatMap(error -> {
                                        log.error("Error calling Notification Service :{}", httpStatus.getReasonPhrase());
                                        if (httpStatus.value() == 400) {
                                            return Mono.error(new BadRequest(error.getMessage()));
                                        }
                                        return Mono.error(new InternalServerError(String.format("Error calling Notification Service : %s", error.getMessage())));
                                    });
                        }
                    });
                }).doOnError(throwable -> {
                    throw new InternalServerError(throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
                });
    }

}
```

How can we trigger this call in async without making the interception wait.. right now processNotification is always returning onComplete signal without executing. The chain is not executing as expected

Comment: Your aspect tries to intercept methods annotated by `@Notify` but your service is not annotated accordingly. Why do you expect it to be intercepted by the aspect?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant by "service is not annotated accordingly"? I'm trying to send a APN notification when the API completes successfully. I use the return value from API service annotated with @Notify to trigger the APN service logic which is not working. if you can share a simple code that helps me use the return value which is of type MONO or FLUX and trigger another autowired services which use reactive completion

Comment: I call the NotificationServiceHelper class in NotifyAspect class which is annotated with `@Aspect` where the `@AfterReturning` advice will be executed when the aspect intercept the pointcut annotated

Comment: What I mean is that your `processNotification` method does not have a `@Notify` annotation, so it will never be intercepted by the aspect.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Log {

     public String title() default "";

}


@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
@Around("@annotation(operlog)")
public Mono<Result> doAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Log operlog) {
    Mono<Result> mono;

    try {
        mono = (Mono<Result>) joinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
    }

    return mono.doOnNext(result -> {
                //doSomething(result);
            };

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get the result from a reactive call,

Will start from a controller and kindly tweak this according to your need

```
@PostMapping(value = UPSERT_CHANGE_REQUEST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<ResponseDTO> upsertChangeRequest(Valid @RequestBody final RequestDTO requestDTO){
   return myservice.getResult(requestDTO);
}
```

And my aspect class

```
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class AuditAspect {

@Before(value = "execution(* com.yourcomapny.services.appname.controller.ChangeRequestController.upsertChangeRequest(..))&& args(changeRequestDTO)", argNames = "auditKey,changeRequestDTO")
public void registerAudit(final ChangeRequestDTO changeRequestDTO) {
    log.info("Before aspect  : {}", changeRequestDTO);
}


@Around(value = "execution(* com.yourcomapny.services.appname.controller.ChangeRequestController.upsertChangeRequest(..)) && args(changeRequestDTO)", argNames = "joinPoint,changeRequestDTO")
public Mono<ChangeRequestDTO> updateResponseAudit(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final ChangeRequestDTO changeRequestDTO) {
    Mono<ChangeRequestDTO> mono;
    try {
        mono = (Mono<ChangeRequestDTO>) joinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
    }
    return mono.doOnNext(data -> log.info("Around aspect {}",data));
}
}
```

you have to call **mono.doOnNext(arg -> print arg)** - for reactive chain to wait for the result, **arg** is the return value or result of that method **upsertChangeRequest** from controller and make sure the name of the arugments in the function matches. If u are using a flux, to get whole response you might need to call collectList().